# How to set backgroundColor for navigationItem?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to format the navigationItem at the top of my main tableView. I've managed to set the title that is displayed by this code

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"MyTitle"];
```

But I haven't found a way to access the backgroundColor. I'd like to something like this

```
[[self navigationItem] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorRed]];
```

But this doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look here:
[change background color of navigation item (bar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568376/change-background-color-of-navigation-item-bar)

Comment: Thanks, I had to play around a bit longer until I finally figured out where to add the proper code!

Comment: Your answer not relates to navigation item.